# Authenticate to Okta OpenID connect using Rest API

Tags: openid-connect, okta, okta-api

I have created a developer openid connect account in okta and integrated my application to authenticate using Okta. So, as soon as the user login to my application, it redirects it to okta page for authentication.

Now, we want some tasks to be automated and using python for automation. The main questions is how to authenticate to application from REST interface using okta

A simple tutorial/example will really help